# Загрузка нескольких файлов

Tags: php

Форма загрузки файлов:

```
<iframe style="display: none;" id="superframe" name="superframeTovNak" enctype="multipart/form-data"></iframe>
<form action=upload.php method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="superframeTovNak">
     <input type="file" multiple name="uploadfile" accept="image/*,image/jpeg" >
     <input name="ScanType" type="text" value="ScanTovNak" style="display: none;" />
     <input type=submit value="Загрузить  сканы" style="">
</form>
```

тег `multiple` позволяет выбрать несколько файлов.
PHP скрипт:

```
if($_FILES['uploadfile']['size'] > 1024*55*1024) // если размер больше 5мб
{
    echo "Размер файла превышает 55мб";
    exit;
}


       if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]))
       {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploaddir.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
       } else {
          echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>"; 
            exit; 
       }
```

При загрузке одного файла все работает хорошо,  если я выбираю несколько файлов, не загружается не чего.

Comment: В начале скрипта php поставьте `var_dump($_FILES);`, чтобы увидеть структуру пришедших данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код не работает, т.к. в случае загрузки множества файлов `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]` является массивом, который содержит имена всех загруженных файлов и вам нужно обрабатывать каждую отдельно. Также необходимо задать аттрибут name для input c квадратными скобками на конце.

```
<input type="file" name="uploadfile[]" multiple>
```

Пример массива:

```
[Files] => Array
(
  [name] => Array
     (
       [0] => 
       [1] => 
       [2] => 
     )

  [type] => Array
     (
       [0] => 
       [1] => 
       [2] => 
     )

  [tmp_name] => Array
     (
       [0] => 
       [1] => 
       [2] => 
     )

  [error] => Array
     (
       [0] => 4
       [1] => 4
       [2] => 4
     )

  [size] => Array
     (
       [0] => 0
       [1] => 0
       [2] => 0
     )
```

)